# How to remove trailing white spaces and "&nbsp;" from the start and end of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, whitespace, trim

If

```
$text = '    &nbsp;    &nbsp; MEANINGFUL THINGS GO HERE &nbsp;&nbsp;     &nbsp;';
```

How can I get

```
$cleanText = 'MEANINGFUL THINGS GO HERE';
```

I know the following will remove all the white spaces

```
$text=trim($text);
```

but how can incorporate actual escaped space into the trim as well?

`Meaningful Things` can contain `[shortcodes]`, html tags, and also escaped characters. I need these to be preserved.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$text = '    &nbsp;    &nbsp; MEANINGFUL THINGS GO HERE &nbsp;&nbsp;     &nbsp;';

$text = preg_replace( "#(^(&nbsp;|\s)+|(&nbsp;|\s)+$)#", "", $text );

var_dump( $text );

//string(25) "MEANINGFUL THINGS GO HERE"
```

additional tests

```
$text = '    &nbsp;  S  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  S   &nbsp;';
-->
string(24) "S  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  S"

$text = '    &nbsp;    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     &nbsp;';
-->
string(0) ""

$text = '    &nbsp;    &nbst;&nbsp;&nbst;     &nbsp;';
-->
string(18) "&nbst;&nbsp;&nbst;"
```

Answer (score 3):

Also run an [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) on this, then trim:

```
$text=trim(html_entity_decode($text));
```

Comment: what if my `meaningful things` so to speak has shortcodes and escaped characters in them, will they be preserved, should i do a reverse conversion in the end. I don't want anything in the `meaningful things` touched.

Comment: You could do an `htmlentities` again afterwards, yes. There is still no _guarantee_ that "meaningful stuff" won't be changed, but it should be, in essence, the same.

Comment: I like the idea, the solution seems really clean and efficient, I think I would be scared to put it into a production code as it depends on PHP's integrity to do these conversions in mirror form. I would test it then I'm not sure how thoroughly I'll be able to test it to be sure its flawless.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @Esailija's *accepted* answer…

What about `&hairsp;`, `&#8202;`, `&VeryThinSpace;`, `&#8201;`, `&thinsp;`, `&ThinSpace;`, etc… Wouldn't this be more complete?

```
$txt = preg_replace('/(^((\&((nbsp)|(((hair)|(very)?(thin))sp(ace)?)|(\#820(1|2)))\;)|(\x{2009}\|\x{200a})|(\s))+|((\&((nbsp)|(((hair)|(very)?(thin))sp(ace)?)|(\#820(1|2)))\;)|(\x{2009}\|\x{200a})|(\s))+$)/imu', '', $txt);
```